# How to create while loops in coffee scripts

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Can anyone explain why the increment i++ in the while loop of this coffescript is placed outside of the while loop when converted to javascript ?

```
if eventtype is 'test'
  i = 0
  while i < platforms.length
    $.ajax
      url: 'myurl/?id=567&platform='+platforms[i]
      .done (response) -> 
        if platforms[i] is 'tv'
          $scope.lolVdatatv = JSON.parse(response)
          alert response
        if platforms[i] is 'phone'
          $scope.lolVdataphone = JSON.parse(response)
          alert response
        if platforms[i] is 'internet'
          $scope.lolVdatainternet = JSON.parse(response)
          alert response
  i++
```

Here is the converted JavaScript:

```
var i;
if (eventtype === 'test') {
  i = 0;
  while (i < platforms.length) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'myurl/?id=567&platform='+platforms[i]
    }).done(function(response) {
      if (platforms[i] === 'tv') {
        $scope.lolVdatatv = JSON.parse(response);
        alert(response);
      }
      if (platforms[i] === 'phone') {
        $scope.lolVdataphone = JSON.parse(response);
        alert(response);
      }
      if (platforms[i] === 'internet') {
        $scope.lolVdatainternet = JSON.parse(response);
        return alert(response);
      }
    });
  }
  i++;
}
```

This is causing the while loop not to exit.

Comment: Indentation matters. Add 2 spaces after `i++` in your coffeescript.

Comment: Did you mean add 2 spaces before? That actually placed the increment in the while loop but why is converted to  _results.push(i++);

Comment: If you have a new question then update it. And, please normalize your indentation

Comment: @Alexander No, if there's a new question it should be posted as a new question, and the answer that answers the original question should be accepted. Moving the goalposts is an annoying practice. (There doesn't seem to be any big [meta] thread discussing this in and of itself but you'll find a few mentions that it's undesireable, and it's clearly unfair to people who've already answered the question well.)

Comment: @millimoose, yeah, in the optimistic scenario where the OP actually does one of those things. Generally, none of that is followed by OPS. It is better to at least achieve one of the two. As for the question, it isn't even worth our time. But, I am giving it time and I haven't voted to close it yet

Comment: @Alexander That's not really my experience, and your comment read as making a recommendation that the OP engage in unwelcome behaviour. I've had success with plain stonewalling any attempts to change the scope of a question once answered, although more so when it was under my answer.

Comment: @millimoose, I'd agree if the question were a valid one to begin with. Too localized, that is what it is

Comment: @Alexander Well, TL was nuked for a reason. This question is valid, just really trivial. Which of course is a good predictor of the asker being the kind that will then struggle with several more "trivial" issues on account of not really knowing what they're doing. (Note to OP: This is not to be taken as judgement, everyone's been there, it's just that it's not in the mandate of SO to be a teaching site - the QA format sucks for that. The point of SO is to be a "better" expert QA site and this includes striving to approximate a certain ideal, *short * question lifecycle.)

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript is, like python, indentation sensitive. You need to have the `i++` statement indented further to be inside the `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < platforms.length
  //do things
  i++
  //still inside.
//this is outside of the loop
```

Comment: The increment is now in the while loop and the array length is 3. Why is  follwoing  executing 3 times before getting to the conditional satements: while i < platforms.length
    $.ajax
      url: 'myurl/?id=567&platform='+platforms[i]
      .done

Comment: @wade: You know that `$.ajax` is asynchronous, right? And what do you think the value of `i` is going to be in your done-callbacks? You might profit from some reading on the [`do` keyword](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) in CoffeeScript.

Comment: @Milligran What you describe is a new problem altogether. Don't try to drag a single person that answered one question already through your whole task, make a new good question about the new problem instead.